# mysql select with 2 different substrings and single WHERE from 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to pull data from sql with several conditions from a single column
how can i get this to work?

```
SELECT RIGHT(productID, 2) AS 'a', SUBSTRING(productID,1,2) AS 'b', productID 
FROM products 
WHERE `group`='$one' 
  AND `a` LIKE 'AA%' 
  AND `b` LIKE '$two'
```

i am trying to get the first 2 letters of the row and last 2 letters from the same row as well as checking if group=$one but get this error

```
    Unknown column 'b' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You haven't shown any data, described what it's supposed to produce, or anything else that we can use to go on. What's not working? What do you expect it to do that it isn't? Post sample data and the what you're trying to get as a result, and someone can help. We can't see your data or read your screen from here; you need to give us the information to help you.

Comment: Logic fails here for me.. right of productID for 2 positions will be only 2 positions long thus can't ever = 'AAA%' and I don't think strings start at position 0 1 for 2 would include 1 & 2 of product ID (though why not just use left)  and you can't reference an aliased field in a where clause. you could either recalculate the values OR wrap it in a select or add a group by/having and use the alias in the having

Comment: ProductID isn't a 0 based index.  Try `SUBSTRING(productID,1,2)` or `LEFT(productID,2)` since you already used right.... and you have an unmatched ) on `right(productID,2)` instead of `right(productID),2)`

Comment: revised the 0 to a 1 but still getting same error: Unknown column 'b' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT(productID, 2) AS 'a', SUBSTRING(productID,1,2) AS 'b', productID 
FROM products 
WHERE `group`='$one' 
GROUP BY productID
HAVING
  a = 'AA' 
  and b LIKE '$two'
```

No need for the like it's two positions % increases execution.

Comment: im still having problems,  does this get the last 2 characters of 'a'?  RIGHT(productID), 2) AS 'a'

Comment: [mySQL string manipulation functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_right)  Right(productID) will return the two right most characters in the PRODUCTID field for the record in question.  substring(productID,1,2) will return the left TWO most characters in productID field.  What's the New error or same error?

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple table (sotest for StackOverFlow Test table) and added a VARCHAR column to it called col1. The code below worked for me.

```
SELECT RIGHT(col1, 2) AS a, SUBSTRING(col1,1,2) AS b, col1 as col FROM sotest  Having a like 'in%' and b like 'te%'
```

The return is as bellow

```
|  a |  b  |     col      |
|'in'| 'te'| 'test_jermin'|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT(productID), 2)
                      ^---extra bracket
```

you're terminating the function before you specify how many characters to extract.

Comment: don't quote the aliases. just have it `AS a` and `AS b`. quoting things like that turns them into strings, and then they're not-aliases.

Comment: MySQL lets you reference alias fields in the where clause?

Comment: @xqbert: yes, it does. very much nicer than mssql/jet.

Comment: Wow Guess [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) needs to update their docs then

Comment: xqbert: the only restriction is that the alias has to be on a non-aggregate result. you can't use a 'where' on (say) a `count(*) as a`, because the count value won't be availble at the time the where decision is being made.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of your error in `RIGHT` function call, you have a misplaced parenthesis. Change the statement of SELECT to this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(productID, 2)
```